# How to throw an exception from JavaScript's callback if it is executed via Selenium's executeAsyncScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to automate some scripts. Most of the functionality is executed using JavaScript endpoints and I could not move this logic to Python:

```
// Python Selenium script 
data = self.driver.execute_async_script('selenium.get_data(arguments)')

// JavaScript placed somewhere on the page tested
selenium.get_data = function(args) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url:'http://servername/ajax_data', 
        success: function(data) {
            args[0](data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            // here I would like to notify selenium that everything is broken
        }
    });
};
```

There is usually some point in the JavaScript where I know that everything is already broken and I would like to raise exception in Selenium script.
Of course I could wait for timeout, but my scripts' timeouts are pretty long and I could not provide additional debug information in the error message.

I've already checked documentation (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) and tests' source code (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/ExecutingAsyncJavascriptTest.java?r=15810).

For now I'm using workaround, that just does not seem good:

```
        error: function(data) {
            window.alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
```

Do you know any better solutions?